# Initialize firebase on Laravel PHP server

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

I wanted to play around with google firebase's custom authentication. But, the documentation only talks about initialisation using node.js or java.

Here's the link : 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup

How do I do that using Laravel PHP? There are a few github projects that I saw, but they are old and I'm not so sure if they will work.

Comment: Have you implemented the firebase auth using credentials in your Laravel project?